# List all available versions of a specific package in NuGet Package Manager Console

Tags: powershell, nuget

What NuGet PowerShell command will return a list of all versions of a specific package?

I have tried the following, but it only returns one version of NUnit along with a number of other (un)related packages, each having only one version.

```
Get-Package -Source https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669 -ListAvailable -Filter NUnit -AllVersions
```

Note: I specify the source URI because we have our own internal package source as our default remote.

My understanding is that the `-AllVersions` switch *should* pull back every version of each matching package.

I can't seem to figure out:

1. Am I doing it wrong?
2. If not, are project maintainers (or someone else) removing older versions from the package source?
3. If they are, why?

Comment: You say it is your internal package source, and then if 2) is the case, why ask 3) here? Go ask them!

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear: The source URI I provided was (apparently, see Alexandre's answer) the nuget v1 package source endpoint. Our internal package source has only internally-developed packages on it, so we need to provide -Source in order to query the official NuGet package source. Hope that helps to clarify. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your source resolves to the version 1 of the feed which doesn't seem to work with `-AllVersions` (I filed an issue: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/563)

Using the V2 feed works for me:

```
get-package -ListAvailable -AllVersions -filter nunit -source https://nuget.org/api/v2/
```

But note that `-filter` is not for a specific package, but more like a search term.

As a workaround, I'd use tab autocomplete to get the versions list of a specific package:

```
install-package -source https://nuget.org/api/v2/ -id nunit -version <tab>
```

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware of the tab autocomplete. That's a much simpler solution than running all of those commands. Thanks a lot. And thanks for opening the issue.

Comment: This is not perfect, we cannot see all versions listed. In my case, if the package has more than 4 versions, only the first 4 are shown while all the remaining are truncated (replaced by `...`). It looks quite pretty and neat with 3 columns, but it cannot show all versions in Versions column. I don't understand why this is acceptable. So if you want to see all available versions, just use the Nuget Package Manager (UI) instead of Nuget Package Console (it becomes useless in this case at least at the moment).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the autocomplete tip for examining the package version(s).  That command-line example had the V1 feed (or some other feed) specified and it did not work for me when pasted verbatim.  However when I substituted the V2 feed url into the `-source` parameter it worked like a charm.  I edited your answer so that the autocomplete example refers to the V2 feed.

Comment: Agree with King King, truncating the list into a single cell is unusable. Is there any way to actually display a list of versions using Find-Package?

Answer (score 13):

As of version 3.x, `get-package -ListAvailable -AllVersions` will still work, but will issue the following warning about imminent deprecation:

> This Command/Parameter combination has been deprecated and will be removed in the next release. Please consider using the new command that replaces it: 'Find-Package [-Id] -AllVersions'.

In addition, [`Find-Package`](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/powershell-reference#find-package) supports an `-ExactMatch` switch which will avoid the wildcard matching issues that `-Filter` has:

`Find-Package NUnit -AllVersions -ExactMatch -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: Imminent deprecation? Imminent removal? Time for an update (with version information and dates)?

Comment: It is worth noting that the version of Find-Package referenced here (with -ExactMatch switch) is not the general PowerShell version; this behvaiour is only available using the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 8):

To extend on the already provided solutions and address the follow-up questions [by King King](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867660/list-all-available-versions-of-a-specific-package-in-nuget-package-manager-conso#comment68568691_11869935) [and JohnKoz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867660/list-all-available-versions-of-a-specific-package-in-nuget-package-manager-conso#comment88237746_11869935), it is possible to get the full list of versions for a specific package as follows:

```
Find-Package -AllVersions -source https://nuget.org/api/v2/ Newtonsoft.Json -ExactMatch | foreach { $_.Versions } | Select-Object Version
```

The package *Newtonsoft.Json* is an example. Replace it as needed.

It works by first getting all versions for a single package (via `-ExactMatch`). This returns a package object that has a *Versions* property, which is an array of version objects. The [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) iterates over all these and the [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) ensures that each version object is output as a single line (by only selecting its main property).

Comment: To include prerelease: `Find-Package -AllVersions -source https://nuget.org/api/v2/ Newtonsoft.Json -IncludePrerelease -ExactMatch | foreach { $_.Versions } | Select-Object OriginalVersion`

Comment: Running this gives me the error "Find-Package: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ExactMatch'."