# How can I see previous version in NuGet Package Manager with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am attempting to manage multiple versions of package in a on-premises NuGet repository. My version numbering did not start out with sufficient care; in one case a new package has a larger build number than the previous. I want developers to be able to choose the correct version.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11869935/117995) mentions how to list all versions with the Package Manager Console.

Is there a way to choose a version or list all versions with the NuGet Package Manager, like you can with the Package Manager Console?

Comment: Install the latest NuGet to VS and you can see a combo box.

Comment: @LexLi this sounds promising, but I'm unable to install the update through Extensions and Updates. "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."